# Index Match Group Issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

I have a range of data where column N displays the unique order number values, column F contains an Action. If the Action value for any of the related order numbers is the same as any other for that group I want to mark these up as , rejected, false, 0 whatever so that I can remove them from the dataset.

In the example graphic I have manually entered True or False in Column Q, but as I have over 10,000 rows, I think I may need a simple formula.

Can someone please advise how to achieve this

Many thanks
[image]

Comment: I started writing a formula for this but it gets a bit complicated (well it does with my knowledge of formulas anyway). Is VBA an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check number of lines with the same combination of Action and Order No. with this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(N:N;N2;F:F;F2)
```

it will give you number of occurences of the combination, so you just need to filter all numbers greater than 1 or change the formula to give rejected, 0, false or whatever you like if the value is greater than 1.

Comment: Hi Pav, thanks for the info, this formula does not work in this instance, i have entered as =COUNTIFS(N:N,N2:F:F:F2) just a typo on your part i guess. All values return 0 for the entire column where the formulas reside. I have taken a screen shot but not sure how to upload via comments.

Comment: the semicolons versus commas is standard thing - I know that many people here have it like you. Regional setting I guess. You put there : instead of some semicolons/commas. Try like this =COUNTIFS(N:N,N2,F:F,F2)

Comment: Hi Pav, thanks again. Understood, almost perfect unless you have alternating Action types, but i think i can weed those out :-)

Answer (score 0):

In a new column, creat concatenate of column F and column N, For example, the new column is R then in cell Q1 put the value 1 and starting from Q2 paste this formula =IF(R1=R2,Q1+1,1)
Once the formula is dragged you can keep only one occurrence of the concatenated value and delete other.[Snip from the Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYz8X.jpg)

[2nd snip attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aJBZ.jpg)

Comment: Hi Chand, thanks for the advice, the formula you have provided will only work if there are two rows per Unique id, in some cases i could have 10 rows. Thanks again

Comment: You need to sort the concatenated column a to z and then use the formula, it's not limited to only 2 occurrences but can count other occurrences as well. Once the column is sorted you can delete values except 1 but keep in mind to paste it as values.

Please see attached 2nd snip in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements:**
Flag as `Delete`, all `Order` numbers with a duplicated `Action` value.
Assuming the data is located from rows `2` to `10105` (over 10,000 rows).

**Solution – Array Formula:**
This Array Formula will return *(eventually)* the required results:

```
= IFERROR( IF( MATCH( $N28,
IF( COUNTIFS( $N$7:$N$10105, $N$7:$N$10105, $F$7:$F$10105, $F$7:$F$10105 ) > 1, $N$7:$N$10105 ),  0 ) > 0,
"Delete" ), "" )
```

Unfortunately, the performance of an Array Formula pointing several times to a range of over 10,000 cells will be extremely slow.

To test the Array Formula over a much smaller range (24 rows only) enter this version of the formula in `Q2` then copy it to `Q3:Q25`:

```
= IFERROR( IF( MATCH( $N2,
IF( COUNTIFS( $N$2:$N$25, $N$2:$N$25, $F$2:$F$25, $F$2:$F$25 ) > 1, $N$2:$N$25 ),  0 ) > 0,
"Delete" ), "" )
```

[image]

**Solution – Standard Formulas:**
The alternative solution would be to use two columns to flag the required records:

1. To identify the orders with duplicated `Action`, enter this formula in `Q2` then copy it to `Q3:Q10105`:

   = IF( COUNTIFS( $N$2:$N$10105, $N2, $F$2:$F$10105, $F2 ) > 1, $N2, "" )

[image]

2. To flag as `Delete` all `Order` numbers identified in step 1, enter this formula in `R2` then copy it to `R3:R10105`:

   = IFERROR( IF( MATCH( $N2, $Q$2:$Q$10105, 0 ) > 0,"Delete" ), "" )

[image]